# Can't use parenthesis ( ) in an entity's attribute value

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I've been experimenting with Orion the last few days and and after a while I made it work the way I intended to.

I am facing an unexpected annoyance though, where a string attribute for a given entity context will fail to register.

Example:

```
http POST [my_orion_server_url]:1026/v1/updateContext < create_push.json
```

Where create_push.json is:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Push",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Push1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "message",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "this is a test)"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

The server replies with:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 129
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 19 Nov 2015 11:47:03 GMT

{
    "errorCode": {
        "code": "400", 
        "details": "Illegal value for JSON field", 
        "reasonPhrase": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

If, on the other hand, I remove the parenthesis, everything works as expected:

json file:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Push",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Push1",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name": "message",
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "this is a test"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

Server response:

```
{
    "contextResponses": [
        {
            "contextElement": {
                "attributes": [
                    {
                        "name": "message", 
                        "type": "string", 
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ], 
                "id": "Push1", 
                "isPattern": "false", 
                "type": "Push"
            }, 
            "statusCode": {
                "code": "200", 
                "reasonPhrase": "OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is this intended or a bug?

I can overcome the issue coding the parenthesis with something else and then decoding on reception, but being able to send a parenthesis straight with the entity would be way smoother and less annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. Please have a look to [Orion documentation](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/user/forbidden_characters/index.html).